# Why image stretch(UIImage to CIImage to UIImage)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, ciimage

Due to some reasons, I need to transform an image from UIImage to CIImage(for processing) and to UIImage back again. I do it by UIImage-CGImage-CIImage-UIImage.Ignoring the irrelevant code, the code is showing behind.

```
UIImage *originalPic = [[UIImage alloc]init];//get this from UIImagePickerController
CIImage *originalCIPic = [[CIImage alloc]init];
originalCIPic = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:originalPic.CGImage];
UIImage *finalResultUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:originalCIPic];

//then I put the image on an Image View(contentMode has been set)
self.viewOfImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; 
self.viewOfImage.image=finalResultUIImage;

//I used NSLog to check the size, but they are the same.(before transforming and after)
NSLog(@"this is the final UIImage,size is %@ ",NSStringFromCGSize(finalResultUIImage.size));
```

But the image showing on the screen is stretched.

What's wrong with me? Or Is there any alternative choice for me?

Thank you very much andI am so sorry I have not enough reputation to post picture.
:)

Comment: Changing imageWithCIImage to imageWithCIImage:scale:orientation doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abcd" ofType:@"png"];
CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
UIImage *imageByCIImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageByCIImage.size);
[imageByCIImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imageByCIImage.size.width,imageByCIImage.size.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
self.imageview.image = newImage;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```